# Strange thing appears while pressing a button two times

Tags: c#, xaml

I made a button that make a page appear and it works well, but when I press it two times a strange windows 7 bar appears.
How can I remove that?
I expect that it does the same thing when is pressed for the first time

What appears: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TIuipPUZ5lP7nvpkWYlUETL8Z94JfVlY/view?usp=sharing

Code:
C#

```
private void Valute(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Symbols.Content = new valuteSymbols();
}
```

XAML

```
<Window Style="{DynamicResource WindowStyle1}" x:Class="Symbol.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Symbol"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Symbol" Height="700" Width="1200"
        Background="#1f2024"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Icon="Res/Logo.ico">


    <StackPanel>

        <Grid Height="100">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="950"/>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Foreground="White" FontSize="25" FontFamily="Asap Bold" Content="$£€" Style="{DynamicResource Button}" Click="Valute" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Height="50" Width="92"/>

        </Grid>



        <Frame x:Name="Symbols" Margin="0,50,0,0"/>

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you expect to occur when the button is pressed a second time.

Comment: I expect that it does the same thing when is pressed for the first time

Comment: You need to add `NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"` to the Frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"` to the frame string.